Problem on showing a function is zero a.e.
Let $f\in L^1(\mathbb R)$ be such that
$$\int_P f(y) dy =0$$
for all Lebesgue measureable sets $P\subset \mathbb R$ with $m(P) = \pi$. Prove that $f(x)=0$ for almost all $x\in \mathbb R$.
In attempt to do this problem, I wanted to partition $\mathbb R$ into intervals of length $\pi$ and then integrate over that partition to get that
$$\int |f|=0$$
but looking back at the hypothesis, we are only given that $\int_P f =0$, which does not necessarily imply that $\int_P |f|=0$, does it?
I am not sure how to get around this and would appreciate any suggestions in a right direction.

Does $\pi$ refer to $3.14159...$?

yes, that's right.

Assuming $f$ is measurable, you likely are expected to define $U={x:f(x)\geq 0}$ and $V={x:f(x)<0}$. Then $m(U)+m(V)=\infty$ so at least one of $U$ or $V$ has infinite measure (and $\infty > \pi$).

Is this hint in direction of partitioning the sets $U$ and $V$ by subsets of measure $\pi$? I am not sure how to gaurantee this could be done.

Assume $m(U)=\infty$ and first just try to show $\int_U f=0$, which would imply $f(x)=0$ for almost all $x \in U$.

Suppose $f$ is not zero almost everywhere. Let $U=\{x: f(x)> 0\}$, let $L=\{x: f(x)<0\}$, and let $Z=\{x: f(x)=0\}$. One of these three sets has infinite measure. If $m(U)$ or $m(L)$ is infinite, the following argument is made easier, so assume $m(Z)=\infty$. By assumption, $m(U)>0$ or $m(V)>0$; say the former holds. Define $E_n= \{x: f(x)> 1/n\}$. Observe that $\bigcup_n E_n = U$. By continuity of measure, we have that $m(U) = \lim_{n\to \infty} m(E_n)$. Hence there exists an $n_0\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $m(E_{n_0})>\frac{1}{2}m(U)$. If $m(E_{n_0})>\pi$, we choose a subset of $E_{n_0}$ of measure $\pi$ to reach a contradiction. If instead $m(E_{n_0})<\pi$, we may consider the union $E_{n_0}\cup Z_0$ where $Z_0\subset Z$ such that $m(Z_0)+m(E_{n_0})=\pi$.

How do we show that there exists a subset of $E_{n0}$ of measure $\pi$?

Suppose $m(E_{n_0})$ is larger than $\pi$. I think it's another good exercise to show that we can choose a subset with exactly measure $\pi$. Most of the mass of $E_{n_0}$ lies on some interval $[-R,R]$. Consider the accumulation function $g(x) = \int_{-R}^x 1_{E_{n_0}}(x), dx$. Then $g(-R)=0$ and $g(R)\approxeq m(E_{n_0})$. If we can show $g(x)$ is continuous, we can apply the IVT to get our result.

Looks good. Another way that focuses only on $[0, \infty)$ is to define $U={x\geq 0: f(x)\geq 0}$, $V={x\geq 0: f(x)<0}$, then $m(U)+m(V)=\infty$.  WLOG assume $m(U)=\infty$ and define $h:[0, \infty)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ by $h(x) = m([0, x]\cap U)$. Then $h(0)=0$,  $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} h(x)=\infty$, and continuity of $h$ follows because for all $x>0$ and all $\delta>0$ (with $\delta<x$) we have $$h(x)-\delta \leq h(x-\delta) \leq h(x+\delta)\leq h(x)+\delta$$

We prove the following generalized version:
Let $c>0$ and suppose $\int_I f dm =0$ for every interval $I$ of length $c$.  Then $f=0$ $m$-a.e.
Let $h(x) = \int_{[x,x+c]} f dm = \int_{[0,x+c]} f  dm - \int_{[0,x]} dm$. Then on the one hand, the assumption implies  $h(x)=0$ for all $x$, and therefore $h'(x)\equiv 0$. On the other hand, the FTC for Lebesuge integrals, $h'(x) = f(x+c) - f(x)$, $m$-a.e.
Combining both:  $f(x+c) = f(x)$, $m$-a.e. which in turn implies that for every $k\in{\mathbb Z}$,  $\int_{[ck,c(k+1)]} |f| dm =\int_{[0,c]}|f|dm$. Since $f\in L^1$, this implies $\int|f|dm = 0$ and therefore $f=0$ $m$-a.e.

+1. This is much better than the other answer and all and suggestions in the comments.
